# Can not access attributes of object in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i am having problems not being able to access the attributes of an object in dart.

I am testing stuff for the database with GetIt, and i currently only have local data stored in a different file in the same program.

So when I try to gather the object data from a file, to use it in a different file where I wilp create the widget,,, the data of the object cannot be accessed.

Cannot even print them in the debug console, I tried print(Student.id) and it returns nothint.

I also tried not using GetIt, just a simple file with a instance of my object created, and it does the same thing.

Is not returning null, it prints

Instance of Object$

Not sure what is going

This is from a file

```
studentProfilecreation tempo =
    studentProfilecreation("Firebaseid1", "A", "B", '', "tdd");
```

This is from a different file, where I want to use the attributes for the widget.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //studentProfilecreation temp =
    //(locator.get<localData>().collectionOfstudents[0]);
    //print(temp);

    studentProfilecreation temp = tempo;
    String id = tempo.id;
    print(id);

    MediaQueryData queryData;
```

It doesnt print anything, but if type print(temp), it prints instance of ObjectX created$

This is object I am trying to get values from

```
class studentProfilecreation {
  String id = "";
  String firstName = "";
  String lastName = "";
  String profileImage = '';
  String major = "";
  String bio = "";
  Map<String, File> coursesAndnotes = Map();
//Constructor
  studentProfilecreation(
    String id,
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    String profileImage,
    String major,
  ) {
    id = id;
    firstName = firstName;
    lastName = lastName;
    profileImage = profileImage;
    major = major;
  }

  studentProfilecreation.studentProfilecreationempty() {
    id = "";
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    profileImage = '';
    major = "";
  }

  studentProfilecreation.createcopy(studentProfilecreation original) {
    id = original.id;
    firstName = original.firstName;
    lastName = original.lastName;
    profileImage = original.profileImage;
    major = original.major;
  }
```

And this is where I Want to the data to create the widget, the rest is just widget stuff

```
class studentProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  String id = "";
  //parameter value will come from tap of student profile from list of viewable students.
  studentProfile(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //studentProfilecreation temp =
    //(locator.get<localData>().collectionOfstudents[0]);
    //print(temp);

    studentProfilecreation temp = tempo;
    String id = tempo.id;
    print(id);
```

Comment: @Autocrab just did

Comment: Please show us studentProfilecreation class (at least, fiedls and constructor)

Comment: @Miamy added more,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor like:

```
studentProfilecreation(
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.profileImage,
    this.major,
  );
```

Now you just overwrite its parameters by themselves without assigning to the fields

UPDATE:

```
class Foo {
  int i = 0;

  Foo(int i) {
    i = i;
  }
}
```

When Dart lexical analyzer is searching for the variable, it looks "from down to up" and stops when first suitable var is found. In my example this is a constructor parameter, not class field (because parameter's definition is closer to the assignment line then field). So if you want to make assignment to the field, you should use

`this.i = i;`

and in this case you'll get a hint

> Use an initializing formal to assign a parameter to a field. Try using
> an initialing formal ('this.i') to initialize the field.

It will be good to have a warning message about assigning variable to itself too. Maybe, in the next Dart version we'll see it :-)

Comment: Thank you, Cant believe I spend 8 hours fixing it lol, is always the small mistakes that hold me back. So could you explain to me a little bit more what my constructor was doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Without code snippet, I can only rule out that the most probable cause is the object retrieved from the local data store **has not been defined as instance of Student class** - hence the print out says *Instance of Object$*

had it been defined as as instance of Student class, the printout would have said *instance of Student* instead.

If that's the culprit, the following steps should give the solution, using flutter as my framework.

First we define Student class, by creating a model folder and then create file - lets call it student_model.dart

```
class Student {
  Student({required this.id, required this.name, required this.course});

  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String course;
}
```

then, let create another folder called database and inside it, a file - let's call it local_data.dart, where we will create a student object - let's call it firstStudent, using Student class we declared earlier in student_model.dart file (don't forget to import this file)

```
import 'package:[*your_project_name*]/model/student.dart';

class LocalData {
  static Student firstStudent =
      Student(id: '123', name: 'John Citizen', course: 'Computer Science');
}
```

finally in any of your file, you can call print as follow

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:[*your_project_name*]/database/local_data.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myStudent = LocalData.firstStudent;
    print(myStudent.id);
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```